# do we need to match package statement and directory of kotlin file in android project?

Tags: android, kotlin

From the kotlin documentation we have ,

> It is not required to match directories and packages: source files can be placed arbitrarily in the file system.

But when i try to specify a package statement on a file that is different from the location of the file in my Android Studio project , i get the following warning:

> Package directive does not match file location .

Anyone knows , why is it happening so ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an IDE inspection in Android Studio, which should only generate a warning (and not an error) by default. Your code will still compile and run fine even if you have this warning - you can suppress it or turn it off freely if you wish.

It's just a convention (especially for mixed language projects) to have the package names match the directory structure, since you're forced to do this for your Java files anyway. From the language's official [coding conventions guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-code-organization):

> In mixed-language projects, Kotlin source files should reside in the same source root as the Java source files, and follow the same directory structure (each file should be stored in the directory corresponding to each package statement).

For pure Kotlin projects, the guide recommends you simplify the nesting of your directories by omitting the common root package:

> In pure Kotlin projects, the recommended directory structure is to follow the package structure with the common root package omitted (e.g. if all the code in the project is in the "org.example.kotlin" package and its subpackages, files with the "org.example.kotlin" package should be placed directly under the source root, and files in "org.example.kotlin.foo.bar" should be in the "foo/bar" subdirectory of the source root).

It's worth noting that this omission of directories has little or no adoption within the community and open source projects, so you might not want to follow the guide on this one, even if the language allows it.

Comment: When you do this, do kotlin android extensions' synthetic properties still work? Not for me...

Comment: You omit but still get warnings , Package directive doesn't match file location

Comment: It is a problem, because when you change the folder of a widget it gets a new package name, so if you have a widget on your home screen it stops working and a message is shown: "Problem loading widget". To avoid it, you need to keep the packge name, but this way this warning appears...